# Get records greater than 1 for same status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table logs

```
   id    status   
   ----------------
   SR123    20 
   SR123    19
   SR123    19  
   SR456    1
   SR456    2
   SR456    2
```

Table 2 status_master

```
     id         status
-------------------------
      1        Verify Email Success
      2        Email verification failed
      19       Send SMS Failed
      20       Send SMS Success
```

So, now I'm trying to get the retry count for each scenario. Expected result

```
status    count
----------------
19          1
1           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like an aggregation of an aggregation to me. Try:

```
SELECT status, [count] = SUM(retries)
FROM (
    SELECT status, retries = COUNT(*) - 1       
    FROM log
    GROUP BY id, status
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) G
GROUP BY status
ORDER BY status
```

Results

| status | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 |

My results were different than your expected results. Did you mean for status = 1 to be status = 2 in your results?

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b828acb424e92570de6ebdea950cad7e).

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware not to use keywords when naming the column like 'status' in your case.

You may need to use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` for your problem

```
SELECT tt.id, COUNT(s.id) as count           
FROM log s INNER JOIN
     status_master tt
    ON tt.id = s.status
GROUP BY tt.id;
```

Here's fiddle for your problem:
[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f45653/6)

Comment: You can use status, you just need to escape it with square brackets.